# Use endswith with multiple extensions

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to detect files with a list of extensions.

```
ext = [".3g2", ".3gp", ".asf", ".asx", ".avi", ".flv", \
                        ".m2ts", ".mkv", ".mov", ".mp4", ".mpg", ".mpeg", \
                        ".rm", ".swf", ".vob", ".wmv"]
if file.endswith(ext): # how to use the list ?
   command 1
elif file.endswith(""): # it should be a folder
   command 2
elif file.endswith(".other"): # not a video, not a folder
   command 3
```

Comment: `file.endswith("")` is always `True`, so your `elif` probably doesn`t do what you think. `"." not in file` might be closer.

Comment: Yes, It should be a folder. Then I must go in this folder to get the file. (I have edited the question to be more explicit)

Comment: You could use `os.path.splitext(filename)` to take the extension out of `filename`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Comment: I found this: elif os.path.isdir(file) == True:

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use a tuple for it.

```
>>> ext = [".3g2", ".3gp", ".asf", ".asx", ".avi", ".flv", \
                        ".m2ts", ".mkv", ".mov", ".mp4", ".mpg", ".mpeg", \
                        ".rm", ".swf", ".vob", ".wmv"]

>>> ".wmv".endswith(tuple(ext))
True
>>> ".rand".endswith(tuple(ext))
False
```

Instead of converting everytime, just convert it to tuple once.

Comment: Instead of converting everytime, just define it as a tuple. i.e. `ext = (".3g2", ".3gp", ...`

Answer (score 17):

Couldn't you have just made it a tuple in the first place? Why do you have to do:

```
>>> ".wmv".endswith(tuple(ext))
```

Couldn't you just do:

```
>>> ext = (".3g2", ".3gp", ".asf", ".asx", ".avi", ".flv", \
                        ".m2ts", ".mkv", ".mov", ".mp4", ".mpg", ".mpeg", \
                        ".rm", ".swf", ".vob", ".wmv")
```

Comment: "ext" should be a list like the accepted answer.