# How to simplify the IF statement in Python 3

Tags: python

I have the IF statement as follows:

```
...
if word.endswith('a') or word.endswith('e') or word.endswith('i') or word.endswith('o') or word.endswith('u'):
...
```

Here I had to use 4 ORs to cover all the circumstances. Is there anyway I can simplify this? I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812785/use-endswith-with-multiple-extensions

Comment: Also here which sort of explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18351977/390450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if word[-1] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
```

where word[-1] is the last letter

Answer (score 3):

Use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

```
>>> word = 'fa'
>>> any(word.endswith(i) for i in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
True
>>> word = 'fe'
>>> any(word.endswith(i) for i in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
True
>>>
```

Comment: like in someone answer's you may also use `"aeiou"` instead of a list `['a', 'e']` since both list and string are iterables in python

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
>>> "apple"[-1] in 'aeiou'
True
>>> "boy"[-1] in 'aeiou'
False
```

Answer (score 0):

`word.endswith(c)` is just the same as `word[-1] == c` so:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

if word[-1] in VOWELS:
    print('{} ends with a vowel'.format(word)
```

will do. There is no need to construct a list, tuple, set, or other data structure: just test membership in a string, in this case `VOWELS`.